# Allowing a parameter to override other parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm working on a report where i need to use 4 parameters. They are SalesId, BeginningDate, Endingdate and SalesType

I need to set these parameters in a way that when a SalesId is entered, other parameters won't be necessary.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can work with datasets for each of the parameters and evaluate the first parameter's value as you receive it. include also a default value for those reports with the same conditional.